# Where do i change text for transactional emails and account dash

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, transactional, email-translation

I know how to create the transactional templates, also for other languages. But I can not figure out where the ordered items and order tax, shipping and order value.

I have searched in app/locale without any result.

For some reason I can not find where to find these translations in order to change the text to my needs.

anyone knows where and how?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the things you see and you cant edit in the transactional emails are PHTML files being called from a block. If you use *nix do

```
find . | xargs grep 'string you want to change' -sl
```

in the console inside app/design/ and you will find where are those strings being used.

The command will return you files where the string you want to change is present, you will be able to change the texts and it will be reflected in your transactional emails.

Comment: OK, this is a bit new to me... what is *nix? and will it be save to just adjust these texts? Won't they be lost on update or can i just copy that file to the theme folder i use

Comment: *nix is what is used to reefer to any Unix distribution. Yes, you should change this in your theme and not in your base theme. If you use any other operating system there will be for sure something like this to search for strings inside a file.

Comment: I'm sorry but this does not help me. I'm using directadmin / apache and don't know much about these things. Is there no other way where to find these transactional emails i need to change?

Comment: I think i need to be able to find the info used in this:  {{layout area="frontend" handle="sales_email_order_invoice_items" invoice=$invoice order=$order}} - to adjust the text

Comment: Keep in mind this is a forum to share knowledge and not to ask for free help you will use for profit. What you need, no matter how, is to find the strings you want to change and change it in the correct design pool.

Comment: I understand, but being new to all of this, i need to learn from the experienced users contributing here don't i :-). I appreciate everyone's time and effort! I found most files in locale nl, now i am only left with finding the part for the invoices...